# MongoDB nodejs driver not returning more than 100000 rows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

This is an example to replicate my issue:

I populate my collection with 1million documents like this:

```
for(i=1; i<=1000000; i++){
if(i%3===0)
     db.numbers.insert({_id:i, stuff:"Some data", signUpDate: new Date()});
else
     db.numbers.insert({_id:i, stuff:"Some data"});
}
```

So, every 3rd document has a signUpDate

I create the following index:

```
db.numbers.ensureIndex({"signUpDate" : 1});
```

Then, I have the following very small app using nodejs:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db
, Connection = require('mongodb').Connection
, Server = require('mongodb').Server
, format = require('util').format;

var host = 'localhost';
var port = Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;

console.log("Connecting to " + host + ":" + port);

Db.connect(format("mongodb://%s:%s/test?w=1", host, port), function(err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection('numbers');

        collection.find({'signedUp': true}, {'_id':1}).limit(100000).toArray(function(err, docs){
                console.log(docs.length)
        });
});
```

This works fine.

However, If I remove the  `.limit(100000)`, the server sits there and never responds.

In a nutshell, all I'm trying to do is return a list of _id's where signUpDate is not null
(there should be around 333,000)

I'm pretty sure the issue is the way mongodb caches, but I'm not sure how I can work around this?

Comment: Aren't you only adding 100,000 docs in your population code?  Maybe that's just a typo.  Regardless, calling `toArray` on a cursor with 333,000 docs is looking for trouble.  You should stream or iterate over the results instead of just dumping them into a massive array.

Comment: I thought that might be where the problem lies... do you have an example of how to stream / iterate?

Comment: OK, I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't call `toArray` on a large result set like this.  Instead, either:

Iterate over the results using [`each`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each):

```
collection.find({'signedUp': true}, {'_id':1}).each(function(err, doc){
    if (doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    } else {
        console.log('All done!');
    }
});
```

or [stream](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream) the results:

```
var stream = collection.find({'signedUp': true}, {'_id':1}).stream();
stream.on('data', function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
stream.on('close', function() {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

Comment: Is there any difference between each and stream as they both return one doc at a time? Besides pause and resume in stream. Thanks Johnny.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the batch size and then stream or iterate the results, otherwise mongo driver sticks everything into the memory.

Also that `{'_id':1}` smells fishy, it probably should be `{fields: {'_id' : 1}}`

So the result in your case would be:

```
collection.find({'signedUp': true}, {batchSize: 1000, fields: {'_id' : 1}}).each(function(err, item) { 
    do something with item
});
```